# When does the error Server Error: Org ID not recognized happen while setting up live agent in sites

Tags: javascript, liveagent

I am receiving the below error when i try to setup live agent from a website.

LIVE AGENT: DOM is ready. Setting up environment.
deployment.js:17 LIVE AGENT: Requesting new session.
deployment.js:17 LIVE AGENT: Received new session ID
deployment.js:17 LIVE AGENT: **Server Error: Org ID not recognized**
deployment.js:17 LIVE AGENT: Disconnecting from Live Agent

Could you please let me know when this issue will happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced this issue recently. Finally hunted down the article that shed some light on it for me: [Live Agent server (endpoint URL) has changed and now Live Agent Chat is no longer working](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000233888&language=en_US).

> **Description**
>
> You may notice that your Live Agent Chat is no longer working, and upon investigation you see that the API endpoint URL (found under Setup | Customize | Live Agent | Live Agent Settings) is different than the URL you have in your webpage's code.
>
> Under Live Agent Settings in Setup:
> [image: Live Agent Settings]
>
> Reference to Endpoint URL in Deployment code:
> [image: Deployment Code]
>
> Example of Deployment code on a webpage:
> [image: Deployment Code on Webpage]
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Notice the URL in the webpage code is different than the URL in the Deployment code. The webpage code starts with 'la2-c1-chi' and the Deployment code shows 'la4-c1-was'. There are 2 references to the API Endpoint URL in the code that is provided via the Deployment. One is 'deployment.js' and the other follows the 'liveagent.init'. These 2 refereces are standard. Now, if the only reference to the API Endpoint URL is within the Deployment code snippet that Salesforce provides, you should see no issues. The system knows how to reroute the call to the correct Live Agent server, so there is no need to update that.
>
> HOWEVER, if you have that API Endpoint URL referenced anywhere else in your webpage code, you MUST update the URL to the new server manually. This is why you SHOULD NOT be hard coding the URL reference within your own code. The Live Agent Server associated to your Org can change without any notice. See the Live Agent Developer's Guide for details on how to correctly handle dynamic endpoint references.
>
> **NOTE: You will have to hard code the Endpoint URL reference within any REST API calls. There is currently no dynamic way to reference this, so you will need to manually update the URL's if the server for your Org changes. Please see "Switch Server Response during Live Agent REST API call" for more information.

TL;DR - it means you aren't using the correct endpoints. You should see somewhere in your code a line that looks like this:

```
liveagent.init('https://d.la2c1cs.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572000000000000', '00D000000000000');
```

You'll get this error if that first parameter (the endpoint) doesn't match what's in your `Live Agent Settings`. You can check this by simply searching `Live Agent Settings` in the `Setup` menu.

[image: Live Agent Settings]

Note that when you include your scripts, you should replace `d.instance.salesforceliveagent.com` with `c.instance.salesforceliveagent.com`.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la2c1cs.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/34.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la2c1cs.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/32.0/prechat.js'></script>
```

I highly advise making these endpoints configurable via `Custom Setting` or `Custom Label`.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks for the find!  In my case, the instance is the same in all places and should I replace d. instance .salesforceliveagent.com with c.instance.salesforceliveagent.com in the liveagent.init line?

Comment: In other words, the endpoint Urls are the same with change only in c.instance or d.instance.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you are using the wrong live agent endpoint OR when you have Visualforce Developer mode activated for your user.